# Drupal commerce (Coupon & Discounts) - Alter rule condition

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a drupal commerce website on which I have add the discout module to make discounts and coupons.
I have in my backoffice a list of all the orders and I can modify them if I want.

The problem is the following :

If I create an order with a discount limited in the time, at the moment when I create the order the coupon is valid and it's added to my order. 
But then, multiple days ago I have to modify this order for some reasons, but now the coupon is expired, and if I update my order then the coupon is recalculed but it's expired so the order doesn't have the discount now.

But I need to have the possibility to add / remove coupon after an order was done. How can I fix this ?

EDIT :

I think this is this one I need to modify :

```
/**
 * Rules condition: Check discount can be applied.
 */
 function commerce_discount_date_condition($discount_name) {
   $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_discount', $discount_name);
   $time = time();

   return $time >= $wrapper->commerce_discount_date->value->value() && $time <= 
   $wrapper->commerce_discount_date->value2->value();
 }
```

But how can I modify it without change the module files, I don't think that this function have a hook ?

And you say that I just have to add the uid 1, but I have some other person that are admin on the site and can modify orders, I think I can add a verification on the roles ?

EDIT 2 :

The function doesn't have a hook but the two functions that call it have one :

```
function commerce_discount_commerce_discount_rule_build($rule, $discount)
```

And

```
function commerce_discount_rules_condition_info()
```

I try to use these hooks in my module (with _alter and without) but they are not triggering, I don't know these functions maybe the rules function are called only certain times ?

Comment: You'll have to edit the coupon rule so it fired if coupon is not expired OR current user id is 1.

Comment: Can you look at my edit ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone need to do the same thing as me, finally I compare the dates of the coupon with the order date, so if a user use a coupon on an order, when I edit it even if the coupon is expired the order still have it.

Here is how I proceed :

First I rewrite the condition 'commerce_discount_date_condition' :

```
  function mymodule_rules_condition_info_alter(&$conditions) {
      $conditions['commerce_discount_date_condition'] = array(
        'label' => t('Check discount dates'),
        'group' => t('Commerce Discount'),
        'parameter' => array(
          'commerce_discount' => array(
            'label' => t('Commerce Discount'),
            'type' => 'token',
            'options list' => 'commerce_discount_entity_list',
          ),
          'commerce_order' => array(
            'type' => 'commerce_order',
            'label' => t('Commerce order'),
            'description' => t('The order the discount would be applied to.'),
            'wrapped' => TRUE,
          )
        ),
        'base' => 'ga_registration_discount_date_condition',
      );
    }
```

I add in this condition the order on which the discount is, so I can use it in the 'base' function :

```
    function mymodule_discount_date_condition($discount_name, $order) {
      $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_discount', $discount_name);
      dsm("cond");
      // Use the order time
      $time = $order->created->value();
      return $time >= $wrapper->commerce_discount_date->value->value() && $time <= $wrapper->commerce_discount_date->value2->value();
    }
```

This function use the order creation time to compare with the discount dates.

The last thing to do was to rewrite the whole commerce_discount_rule_build hook (The only thing that changes are in the end) :

```
function mymodule_commerce_discount_rule_build($rule, $discount) {
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_discount', $discount);
  $discount_offer = $wrapper->commerce_discount_offer->value();
  $wrapper_discount_offer = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_discount_offer', $discount_offer);

  // Check if property is attached to commerce free shipping!
  if (isset($wrapper_discount_offer->commerce_free_shipping)) {
    if (!$shipping_service = $wrapper_discount_offer->commerce_free_shipping->value()) {
      // No need to change the rules event.
      return;
    }

    // Add missing parameter.
    foreach ($rule->actions() as $action) {
      if ($action->getElementName() == 'commerce_discount_free_shipping_service') {
        $action->settings['shipping_service'] = $shipping_service;
      }
    }
  }

  // Product level discounts must pass the line item's order.
  $map = array(
    'order_discount' => 'commerce-order',
    'product_discount' => 'commerce-line-item:order',
  );

  if (isset($map[$discount->type])) {
    // Add condition for per-person usage.
    if ($wrapper->discount_usage_per_person->value()) {
      $rule->condition(
        'commerce_discount_usage_max_usage_per_person',
        array(
          'commerce_discount' => $discount->name,
          'order:select' => $map[$discount->type],
          'usage' => $wrapper->discount_usage_per_person->value(),
        )
      );
    }
    // For normal usage.
    if ($wrapper->discount_usage_limit->value()) {
      $rule->condition(
        'commerce_discount_usage_max_usage',
        array(
          'commerce_discount' => $discount->name,
          'order:select' => $map[$discount->type],
          'usage' => $wrapper->discount_usage_limit->value(),
        )
      );
    }
  }

  if (!empty($discount->commerce_discount_date)) {

    $types = commerce_discount_types();
    $type = $types[$discount->type];
    // On désactive pas les règles des discounts
    $rule->active = TRUE;

    // Ajoute la condition
    $rule->condition('commerce_discount_date_condition', array(
      'commerce_discount' => $discount->name,
      'commerce_order:select' => $type['entity type'] == 'commerce_order' ? 'commerce-order' : 'commerce-line-item:order',
    ));

  }

}
```

What i change is all the things inside the last if, I always set the rule to active (normally rules are desactivated when the discount is expired), and I add to the rule the condition with the discount name and the order.
If I rewrite the whole hook it's because the `$rule->condition` add a condition, even if I add a condition with the same name it's added and not updated, so if I just use the hook without unset the base function I have the original condition and mine in the rule.

So, I unset the module only for this hook :

```
function mymodule_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook)
{
  if ($hook == 'menu_alter') {
    // Move ga_registration_menu_alter() to the end of the list.
    $group = $implementations['ga_registration'];
    unset($implementations['ga_registration']);
    $implementations['ga_registration'] = $group;
  }
  if ($hook == 'commerce_discount_rule_build'){
    unset($implementations['commerce_discount']);
  }
}
```